# Trying to plot in tmap shapefile with attribute

Tags: r, plot, shapefile, qgis, tmap

I am trying to work with municipality data in Norway, and I'm totally new to QGIS, shapefiles and plotting this in R. I download the municipalities from here:
[Administrative enheter kommuner / Administrative units municipalities](https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/kartverket/administrative-enheter-kommuner/041f1e6e-bdbc-4091-b48f-8a5990f3cc5b)

Reproducible files are here:
[Joanna's github](https://github.com/Joannagit/Municipality)

I have downloaded QGIS, so I can open the GEOJson file there and convert it to a shapefile. I am able to do this, and read the data into R:

```
library(sf)
test=st_read("C:/municipality_shape.shp")
head(test)
```

[image: head]

I have on my own given the different municipalities different values/ranks that I call **faktor**, and I have stored this classification in a dataframe that I call **df_new**. I wish to merge this "classification" on to my "test" object above, and wish to plot the map with the classification attribute onto the map:

```
test33=merge(test, df_new[,c("Kommunekode_str","faktor")],
             by=c("Kommunekode_str"), all.x=TRUE)
```

This works, but when I am to plot this with `tmap`,

```
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(test33) + 
  tm_fill(col="faktor", alpha=0.6, n=20, palette=c("wheat3","red3")) + 
  tm_borders(col="#000000", lwd=0.2)
```

it throws this **error**:

```
Error in object[-omit, , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of
dimensions
```

If I just use base plot,

```
plot(test33)
```

I get the picture:

[image: result of map plot]

You see I get three plots. Does this has something to do with my error above?

Comment: Dear editor: it does not seem like the link works after the edit! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, don't post data as images, you need to make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038) for Stack Overflow, cheers.

Comment: I'm trying to make a good question =(

Comment: Probably you need to help us first with that we can help you. You have read my link above? Basically adding the output of `dput(test33)` to your question would help.

Comment: @jay.sf: Ok, I understood what you meant, I have added the files here so everything is reproducible: https://github.com/Joannagit/Municipality

Comment: @jay.sf: Thank you for helping me! I added dput of test33 to my github repository as well!

Comment: Thanks, brought your `dput` to work with `readRDS("dput_test33.rds")`. I think you need to add `tm_polygons()` somehow: `tmap_mode("view"); tm_shape(test33, projection="longlat") + tm_polygons() + tm_fill(col="faktor", alpha=0.6, n=20, palette=c("wheat3","red3"))`. At least Norway shows up, without colors, though. Maybe the warning helps you further :) If you don't get an answer here from anybody more familiar with this, could try asking on [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (Feel free to write an answer yourself if you figured it out.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't understand the error, but that is no surprise, I have no understanding of shapefiles, layers or any of this, but I appreciate the help =)

Comment: Btw, if anybody knows any other way of plotting this, it doesn't need to be using tmap, I would be grateful=)

Comment: @Joanna I can help with this. Can you clarify a couple of things first? 1) Would you prefer an interactive map as in your example? 2) what colour scale are you trying to achieve? Your breaks are currently using 0-1.2 in increments of 0.5, did you have a particular break scheme in mind?

Comment: Thank you so so much! I am completely new to this so I'm just trying to achieve a map where I can see the differences in "faktor" between the municipalities in a nice way. I do not know if the map should be interactive or not, and I do not know much about colour scales or break schemes. I'm so sorry that I'm answering this badly, I hope you can help me!

Comment: Ah, it was the missing values for "faktor" that was the problem =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that the shapes you are trying to plot are too complex so `tmap` is struggling to load all of this data. `ggplot` also fails to load the polygons.

You probably don't need so much accuracy in your polygons if you are making a choropleth map so I would suggest first *simplifying* your polygons. In my experience the best way to do this is using the package `rmapshaper`:

```r
# keep = 0.02 will keep just 2% of the points in your polygons.
test_33_simple <- rmapshaper::ms_simplify(test33, keep = 0.02)
```

I can now use your code to produce the following:

```r
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(test_33_simple) +
  tm_fill(col="faktor", alpha=0.6, n=20, palette=c("wheat3","red3")) + 
  tm_borders(col="#000000", lwd=0.2)
```

[image]

This produces an **interactive** map and the colour scheme is not ideal to tell differences between municipalities.

### static version

Since you say in the comments that you are not sure if you want an interactive map or a static one, I will give an example with a static map and some example colour schemes.

The below uses the `classInt` package to set up breaks for your map. A popular break scheme is 'fisher' which uses the fisher-jenks algorithm. Make sure you research the various different options to pick one that suits your scenario:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(classInt)

breaks <- classIntervals(test_33_simple$faktor, n = 6, style = 'fisher')



#label breaks
lab_vec <- vector(length = length(breaks$brks)-1)
rounded_breaks <- round(breaks$brks,2)
lab_vec[1] <- paste0('[', rounded_breaks[1],' - ', rounded_breaks[2],']')
for(i in 2:(length(breaks$brks) - 1)){
  lab_vec[i] <- paste0('(',rounded_breaks[i], ' - ', rounded_breaks[i+1], ']')
}


test_33_simple <- test_33_simple %>%
  mutate(faktor_class = factor(cut(faktor, breaks$brks, include.lowest = T), labels = lab_vec))

# map
ggplot(test_33_simple) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = faktor_class), size= 0.2) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: You should look through the `style` options listed in `?classIntervals` and research a suitable class structure. Changing the class intervals can impact on the message the map portrays.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I am so happy now=)